# Checking how/where a path gets mounted from

Tags: linux, mount

I mounted a network share (CIFS) long time back to be mounted into a specific folder. Now I don't even have that folder mapped anywhere in /etc/fstab. I'm also mostly sure I mounted it manually (not automatically from /etc/fstab).

However, when I perform 'sudo mount -a', along with other things, that path gets mounted too. Any way to check where this is getting mounted from, if it does not exist in /etc/fstab?

I've tried the following terminal commands and none of them pick up/show this particular folder.

```
mount
gvfs-mount -l
smbstatus
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see what the kernel actually has mounted do this:

```
cat /proc/mounts
```

If it's not in there then it's not mounted.

Comment: I had come to that conclusion myself, but thanks for the response!